# Mutex on windows xp gives 0xC0000096: Privileged instruction exception

Tags: c++, windows-xp, mutex

I try to initialize a mutex (VS 2008/windows xp sp2), but each time I run my app, the line:

```
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
```

gives me the following error:

```
0xC0000096: Privileged instruction.
```

I declare my mutex with:

```
static pthread_mutex_t mutex;
```

I tried to not call pthread_mutex_init declaring my mutex like:

```
static pthread_mutex_t mutex= PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

but

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
```

crash with the 0xC0000096: Privileged instruction error.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you must use the `CreateMutex` API to initialize a mutex object.
Or you can use the new C++ `mutex` class, provided your compiler supports it.

Comment: I used the Windows API but I need to do one version of my app for linux, and one for windows. If I solve the `Privileged instruction error` I'll post it, but for now the Windows API is the best way to avoid the problem.

Comment: You can use the C++11 `mutex` class which will work in Windows and Linux.

Comment: I'm not sure if C++11 is supported in VS2008.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize you're using VS2008. C++11 is not supported in VS2008. However, you can use the Boost library. Boost has a mutex class.